# How do I get data from one column to other column in sql

Tags: sql, plsql

How do I get data from one column to another column

In sql I tried to get data from one column to another column

And after getting result from another column I need data for all days like Monday to Sunday

Column name should be Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday and sunday

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, if you want a good answer to your question, make sure to ask a good question. There are some resources on how to do so: [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: update tablename set column2 = column1? Sample data and expected results would help a lot.